# how to call another call method in other class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please read my question first do not mark it as duplicate. In many frameworks like codeigniter etc. I have seen they call core class method like,

```
$this->load->view ();
```

So I am trying to achieve it with core PHP. I have two classes test and test2. How I can call the test method into test2 like

```
$this->test->index();
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call method from Class B into Class A.

Class A have to Extend Class B

```
class test extends test2 {
}
```

Or you have to have smth like:

```
class test {


    function runTest2method() {
        $this->test2method();
    }


    function test2method() {

        $Test2 = new test2();

        $userIt = $test2->test2classmethod();

    }
}
```

In yii2 for example to use one class methods in another one you are just using static functions like:

```
use common\models\User;

class controller {

function somefunction() {

$user = User::userFunction();

}
```

Comment: i want like $this->classB->method(); ? is this possible

Comment: $this is reserverd only for current object methods and properties

Comment: thn how does in codeigniter they call method with this from different clas

Comment: Declare method: that creates new object of other class, use other class method inside, then use the method u have declared as $this->method_with_test2_object()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function test1()
{
    $total = $this->test2();//calling test2() function
    echo $total;
}

public function test2()
{
    $sum = 1+2;
    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: test1 and test2 are diffrent class ... and they have method1 and method2

if if class method 2 in test class .. i want like this .. $this->test2->method2(); is this possible ?

Comment: so use this in model. you can access all in the controller

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BDL so can you explain how post this kind of answer with these styles and  commenting it??

Comment: As op already commented: You are not taking into account that the two methods are not members of the same class.

Comment: @BDL learn about codeigniter you will get know about how to call function in same controller

Answer (score 0):

Please try it.....

```
<?php
    $result = test2();
    function test1()
    {
        $sum = 1+2;
        return $sum;
    }

    function test2()
    {
        $total = test1();//calling test2() function
        echo $total;
    }
    ?>
```